# A issue of Laravel 5.2 with AngularJS 2.0 beta

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, laravel-5

I have installed a fresh [Laravel 5.2.* project](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2). I have trying to config the project with AngularJS 2.0 beta using [the quick start instruction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). However, I have faced some problems. 
According to the following screenshot, main.js was not found. What is wrong here? I was wondering if you check this configuration?

[image]
The project structure:
proj_name
-resources
--assets
---typescript
----app.component.ts
----main.ts

Answer (score 0):

Elixir assumes your file is in *resources/assets/js*, so you should make your structure *resources/assets/js/typescript/main.js* and then mix the file like this: `mix.typescript('typescript/main.js', ...`

Comment: I have tried that. But it wasn't help.   - resources\assets\typescript\typescript\main.js <-- Not Found

Comment: @TugsbayarBuyadaa you should have in within a *js* folder - *resources/assets/js/typescript/main.js*.